# How to parse and understand the sentence in bold?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It's only 4 hours flying time from Sydney, but a world
>   away.***What better place to rest than a country where the only
>   place people hurry is on the football field and things are done in
>   "Fiji time"?***

Answer (score 6):

It's not, formally a complete sentence.

The idiom *What ADJer NOUN than Y?* is a colloquial abbreviation for *What NOUN **is** ADJer than Y?*

> What more romantic place than Paris? = What place is more romantic than Paris?
>   What better man for the job than Chris? - What man is better for the job than Chris?

The idiom *NOUN to VERB* in this context means *NOUN for VERBing*.

Consequently, your example may be understood as

> What place is better for resting than a country where
>   [a] the only place people hurry is on the football field and
>   [b] things are done in "Fiji time"?

Comment: @StoneyB.So you means this structure of "What better place to rest" is correct? I have never seen such a wired structure.

Comment: @user48070 Well, this is a good place to start. What better? :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a type of **minor sentence**.  It's a rhetorical *wh*-question, and its structure is very simple:

> *wh*-word + *comparative*

Since it's a rhetorical question, no answer is expected.  Instead, the question is used to imply a superlative about the topic of discussion:

> What [ better place to rest than **a country where the only place people hurry is on the football field and things are done in "Fiji time"** ] ?

Here, the rather long noun phrase is the topic, referring to Fiji.  The implication is that there is no valid answer to the question, and therefore there is no better place to rest.  As a result, this question is understood as a superlative statement about Fiji with the following meaning:

> **Fiji** is the best place to rest (because it's **a country where the only place people hurry is on the football field and things are done in "Fiji time"**).

Since it's a type of minor sentence, it doesn't fit any of the major sentence patterns you typically encounter.

Comment: @godel9 Thank you.  I appear to have reading comprehension problems. ;-)